# Expand/shrink div on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

i've been practicing some expand/shrink on click html/css/jquery, but some reason, it isnt working. I know there are some out there but i've tried them out, none is working with my code.

PS: for now im trying to expand one

My objective:

Using 4 div squares, all are clickable (like a menu), when a user clicks, it expands for a full page and load content (it can be external html or same code on the index.html page), and of course, have a "close" icon/image on the corner.

From the position the square is, i want it to expand to full page, with some basic width/height transition, with a bit fade out (kinda material design).

What's wrong with my code?

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="menu1">
        <!-- quadrado 1 -->
    </div>

    <div id="menu2">
        <!-- quadrado 2 -->
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="menu3">
        <!-- quadrado 3 -->
    </div>

    <div id="menu4">
        <!-- quadrado 4 -->
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
    display: inline;
    width: 400px; 
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu1.fullscreen{
    z-index: 9; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: #131313; 
}

#menu1, #menu2, #menu3, #menu4{display: inline-block; width:200px; height:200px;}

#menu1{background: red;}
#menu2{background: green;}
#menu3{background: blue;}
#menu4{background: orange;}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".content").click(function(e){
        $("#menu1").toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a7nzy6w6/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the click event inside the scroll event. That means that you have to click while on scroll.

try it like this only

```
$(".content").click(function(){
    $("#menu1").toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
});
```

or wrap it inside the document ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").click(function(){
        $("#menu1").toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
    });
});
```

And remove the (e) from click(e) ... write it just click()
Let me know if that worked

Answer (score 1):

Why `$(window).scroll(function(){...});` and not `$(document).ready(function(){...});`?

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").click(function(e) {
    $("#menu1").toggleClass('fullscreen');
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: inline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu1.fullscreen {
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #131313;
}
#menu1,
#menu2,
#menu3,
#menu4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#menu1 {
  background: red;
}
#menu2 {
  background: green;
}
#menu3 {
  background: blue;
}
#menu4 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div id="menu1">
    <!-- quadrado 1 -->
  </div>

  <div id="menu2">
    <!-- quadrado 2 -->
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div id="menu3">
    <!-- quadrado 3 -->
  </div>

  <div id="menu4">
    <!-- quadrado 4 -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: dumb me, copyed wrong function :3 my bad. Still, my goal is to expand all divs, with material design effect (like android)

Comment: You only expand menu1

Comment: @mplungjan I definitely have to adapt my answer.

Comment: I tried. I gave the divs a class menu and expected `.menu.fullscreen` to work but it didn't

Comment: @mplungjan That was probably because of the ID overrides, anyway I'll refactor that later today. Furthermore, I think that the desired effect was to expand all div elements with the corresponding colors with some animation.

Comment: Yes - yours expands only one of them and changes the bgcolor

Answer (score 0):

By placing your code within the callback function for `$(window).scroll()`, you are making it so that you have to be scrolling and at the same time clicking before you reach the code that in indie the callback function for `(".content").click()`.

Try placing your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` because that will ensure that the DOM is ready for manipulation and then your code will run fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").click(function(e){
        $("#menu1").toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
    });
});
```